# list of indexes in NSArray from NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

My question is very similar to : [obj c -get list of indexes in NSArray from NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344435/obj-c-get-list-of-indexes-in-nsarray-from-nspredicate)

But there is a difference. I have two NSArrays. The first is of names and the other is of phone numbers. I search into the "names" array to search for a name using the following code:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchtext scope:(NSString *)scope {

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",searchtext];
self.searchResult = [ForMsgNamrarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}
```

I am returned a filtered array which is fine. But based on the indexes of the filtered array I would also like to filter the array containing the phone numbers.

For example if I search "jh" I get "Jhone" in my search array. I also want to add the phone number of john in another array i.e "searchArrayPhNum"

Comment: Do one simple thing. Preapre a dic for each record which contain Name and phonenumber as keys and add them in array. and do the filter as you want..

Comment: I don't think that using two "linked like this" NSArray  is a good architecture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare a Model Object with following properties,

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *phoneNumber;
@end
```

and use single array ( an array of `Person` objects) instead of Two different arrays,
Your predicate would change like,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@",searchtext];
```